# How to access JQuery Plugin Extended Methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm currently working with a JQuery Plugin called Raty (among many others), as normal the plugin does the following:

```
(function($){
       $.fn.raty = function(settings, url){
            // Some default operations
            // Some functions
            this.activate = function(){}
            this.reset = function(){}
       };
});
```

Then in my code, I call it by doing so:

```
$('#someDivId').raty();
```

The problem occurs, when I want to call one of these extended methods (e.g. reset()) on the "someDivId", I look for it at a later stage with jquery $('#someDivId') but when I execute any of the extended methods on it, an error occurs (the object seems to not have these methods attached to it).

This is the piece of code which is not working:

```
$('#someDivId').activate();
```

My question is, do you know if it is possible at all to access these methods from outside the plugin? And if not, do you know a generic way of doing this?

In the current example I ended up adding a hidden link which can be clicked to trigger any of these methods. (But it still an ugly hack for me :P)

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new here and didn't knew that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#someDivId').raty();` will attach the functions to this particular jQuery object instance. When you call `$('#someDivId')` again, a new instance will be created.

You have to keep a reference to the original instance:

```
var $div = $('#someDivId').raty();
// later
$div.activate();
```

This assumes that `raty()` is a good citizen and returns `this`. If not, you have to make the reference first:

```
var $div = $('#someDivId');
$div.raty();
```

Comment: Hi Felix, Thanks for your quick answer. The problem is that many objects on the web site are using this plugin (Each comment has one). So it is impossible to mantain a reference of all this objects. At any time, if the user disables a comment, then at that point the activate / deactivate method of the rating element of that comment should be called.

Is then what I trying to do not possible at all, or am I still missunderstanding something?

Comment: @Nicolas: If you have a lot of them, then you might have to use a hashmap (an object) to store the references. E.g. the selector could be the key and the jQuery object the value. Something like `elements[selector] = $(selector).raty();`. You probably have to provide more information and explain what the plugin is doing so we can help you more.

Comment: But it is not possible at all to tell the plugin to not create a new instance, but rather use the old one? So those methods are extended there? Or use the element id to access to (somehow) to the jquery instances availalbe and search for it there? Mataining such a hashtable would be impossible, since the page is partially updated each 3 seconds.

Comment: @Nicolas: You cannot change the internals of jQuery. Whenever an selector is evaluated it will create a new jQuery object, even for the same selectors. You might be able to change the plugin and maybe attach relevant information with `.data()`... or maybe you should take a totally different approach at all...

Comment: Hi Felix, thanks for your quick reply. If I understand it correctly, even extending the object with prototype wont work. So may first attempt (creating hidden links with events attached to them and then triggering those links events to execute an action) is not that bad at all? Is there a native way of achieving the same behavior? (JS triggers or something like that?

Comment: @Nicolas: Actually I don't understand how the hidden links solve your problem ;)

Comment: Its quite simple. I just add into the div component (#someDivId) a link which is hidden. And bind the click even of this link to the activate() function. At that point, the reference to the instance is know. At a later stage i can call: $("#someDivId a#someIdLink").click() and fire the activate function without knowing the instance. But again, it works but it is for sure a ugly hack :D